# Weak convergence in $L^1$ of $\sin(2\pi n x)$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Is it possible to show that $\sin(2\pi n x)$ tends to $0$ weakly in $L^1([0,1])$ (with respect to the Lebesgue measure)? That is, to prove that
$$
\int_{[0,1]}\sin(2\pi nx )g(x)\,\mathrm{d}{x} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0
$$
for any function $g\in L^\infty([0,1])$. I am working on different convergence results for $\sin(2\pi nx)$ but got stuck on this one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Prove it for simple functions, then extend to $L^\infty$ via uniform approximation.

Comment: @AlexR. How do I go about proving the result for simple functions? I can see how to do it for step functions, but step functions are not dense in $L^\infty$

Comment: This is actually true if $g\in L^1.$ See the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Riemann-Lebesgue theorem we have if $g$ is integrable function then 
$$\lim_n \int e^{-inx}g(x)\,dx=0$$
In your situation you've got $g\in L^{\infty}[0,1]$. In particular this implies
$$\int^1_0g(x)\,dx\leqslant \int^1_0|g(x)|\,dx\leqslant \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|g(x)|\int^1_0\,dx=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|g(x)|<+\infty$$
hence $g\in L^1[0,1]$. By the theorem above we get 
$$\lim_n\int^1_0e^{-inx}g(x)\,dx=0\Rightarrow \lim_n\Im\Big(\int^1_0e^{-inx}g(x)\,dx\Big)=0\Rightarrow \lim_n\int^1_0\sin(nx)g(x)\,dx=0$$
For a proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue theorem you can refer to almost any standard book in real analysis.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing that :-)